# Cookie's value is doubled without any reason

Tags: c#, cookies, httpcontext, namevaluecollection

I've got an problem with Cookie.
That's the code:

```
NameValueCollection ncook = new NameValueCollection();
ncook = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["history"].Values - in that line
```

What is in my cookie:

> item_0=nonpacket-program.aspx?id=360ANDcourse=1044ANDcenter=238ANDfeeding=ANDinhabitation=

That's what I expect to recieve from the line showen before.
And here it is what I actualy recieve:

> item_0=nonpacket-program.aspx%3fid%3d360ANDcourse%3d1044ANDcenter%3d238ANDfeeding%3dANDinhabitation%3d&item_0=nonpacket-program.aspx%3fid%3d360ANDcourse%3d1044ANDcenter%3d238ANDfeeding%3dANDinhabitation%3d

How you can see the value is doubled. And that's the problem.... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're showing us the code where you *retrieve* the cookie, but if you're getting doubled-up results the problem likely exists in the code where you *set* the cookie.

Comment: I showed you what lies in  the cookie and there is nothing more but other items (item_1,2,3....) So I believe I set cookie right but if you still believe that there might be something wrong I can send it to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thought is that you are assigning ncook the value of an existing cookie, and then a postback happens, and the "history" cookie now has two entries in its values. the "history" cookie is a history, so for each postpack, I'm betting the history cookie grows, and thus, ncook will grow as well.

Comment: Hi. I founded what you said. In one class I request cookie to set it up and I need to check for the same values first and in other class I call it again to create a list on an web page... Is that possible to have any trick here?

Comment: Problem solved. Now I call cookie one time and keep them in session